# Appium : how to test webappication in chrome on windows 10?

Tags: c#, windows, automated-tests, appium

I am trying to automate tests for a web application running in chrome on Windows 10 using Appium.
I have code like below that works perfectly fine uses chromedriver. I want to move this to appium based approach.

```
RemoteWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\chromedriver_win32");
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));

driver.Url = "https://www.bing.com/";
RemoteWebElement element = (RemoteWebElement)driver.FindElementById("sb_form_q");
element.SendKeys("webdriver");
element.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
wait.Until(x => x.Title.Contains("webdriver"));
```

I searched internet and find a lot of code to test webapplications on chrome on android emulators on windows devices. I did not find any sample that runs chrome browser directly on windows 10.
Based on what i understood, i tried adopting the code by making changes to desired capabilities like below.

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.Chrome();
caps.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "chrome");
caps.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Version, "60");
caps.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, "Windows 10");
caps.SetCapability("platformName", "Windows");
//caps.SetCapability("app", @"C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\Chromedriver.exe");
caps.SetCapability("app", @"Chrome");
caps.SetCapability("deviceName", "WindowsPC");

driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4725/wd/hub"), caps, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
driver.Url = "https://www.bing.com/";
((IWebDriver)driver).Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.bing.com/");
RemoteWebElement element = (RemoteWebElement)driver.FindElementById("sb_form_q");
element.SendKeys("webdriver");
element.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);

Thread.Sleep(5000);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
wait.Until(x => x.Title.Contains("webdriver"));
```

This however doesn't work.
I think the problem is I am not able to figure out how to set desired capabilities so that appium service running on http://127.0.0.1:4725/wd/hub is able to launch chromedriver and run tests.

Can someone please help point out mistake with the above code?
Appreciate your help.

Comment: I am facing a similar need. I am having a desktop application with cef browser and I want to open the cef window in chrome and automate it. Can you please provide here any additional findings you got on this?

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass the capabilities of the android phone not the windwos pc as you passes

```
caps.SetCapability("platformName", "Windows");
```

Like that and you need to pass the OS version of the emulator or android phone if you are using it..

For reference visit this site you will know everything that you need to know..

http://www.automationtestinghub.com/launch-chrome-browser-on-mobile-device/

Happy to help..  let us know if that solution works for you

Comment: just to clarify, I am trying to run the test on Windows 10 and not on android. Thanks.

Comment: but you said you need to run test on emulator right

Comment: sorry if i was unclear, so here is the thing. I am trying to run the test on windows 10 in chrome browser. next, i'll try test the same web application through chrome embedded(CEF) in wpf application

Answer (score 0):

As nicely put up here - https://crossbrowsertesting.com/blog/appium/appium-native-web-hybrid-applications/

Appium is an open source test automation frameworktes that drives iOS and Android native, mobile, and hybrid apps using the WebDriver protocol a.k.a. The Selenium API. That’s to say, Appium is like Selenium’s cousin, and used for testing mobile apps **instead of web applications in desktop browsers**.

Per the discussion here - https://discuss.appium.io/t/can-appium-automate-desktop-web-browsers/746/5 too it seems appium is for testing on mobile devices only.